# "Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync" is ignoring the attachment field

Tags: c#

```
var mailto = new Uri("mailto:?to=mailto&subject=" + subject.ToString() + "&body=" +body + "&attachment=F:/Windows.txt");
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```

I am using the above code to send mail, Here 'To mail address', 'body', 'subject' are reflecting in the Gmail app but attachment is not reflecting.

Comment: how to generate mail with "to receipt" and "attachment" in windows 8.1